# Using Angular.js expressions inside script tags: is it possible or should I just use a directive?

Tags: angularjs, disqus

I'm building out a pretty basic app/site to list events, and am including Discus as a comments platform on each individual event page. I can get Discus to load up just fine with standard settings, but would like to use the (slightly) more advanced scripted settings that Discuss comes with to make sure each comment thread is in the right place and tracking the right thing.

My issue is getting Angulars {{}} expressions to resolve inside the script tags - they aren't at the moment. Is there a way to get around this easily or should I just stop being lazy and build out some dedicated behind-the-scenes logic to handle displaying Discus?

Here's the code that isn't working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
        var disqus_shortname = 'thesgcespartylist'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
        var disqus_identifier = '{{theID}}';
        var disqus_title = 'S&G CES 2014 Party List: {{party.Title}}';

        /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
</script>
```

And the page in question is http://cespartylist.stuntandgimmicks.com/index.html#/party/best-party-1

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you could use $interpolate. From their website:

```
var $interpolate = ...; // injected
var exp = $interpolate('Hello {{name}}!');
var output = exp({name:'Angular'});
```

Read more here: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interpolate](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate)